All texts in Jupyter R plot in get scrambled if Cairo package is installed
When I plot in a Jupyter + R session, whether it is a Notebook or R console, base R or ggplot2 plots, texts all get scrambled like this:

sessionInfo:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/adam/opt/mambaforge/envs/R433new/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.27.so;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: US/Central
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.37     IRdisplay_1.1     utf8_1.2.4        base64enc_0.1-3  
 [5] fastmap_1.2.0     glue_1.7.0        htmltools_0.5.8.1 repr_1.1.7       
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.4   cli_3.6.3         fansi_1.0.6       vctrs_0.6.5      
[13] pbdZMQ_0.3-11     Cairo_1.6-3       compiler_4.3.3    tools_4.3.3      
[17] evaluate_0.24.0   pillar_1.9.0      crayon_1.5.3      rlang_1.1.4      
[21] jsonlite_1.8.8    IRkernel_1.3.2    uuid_1.2-1 

Notice that Cairo is loaded.
However, if I launch an R session in Linux terminal, or if set output to a pdf/png file, or if I uninstall Cairo package and start a new Jupyter session, all texts will be normal. Texts in plots remain normal even if I do library('Cairo') in a Linux terminal session. I am using R-4.3.3 in above code only because I thought the issue was with latest R, which turned out to be wrong.  Any idea? Thank you very much!
I tried conda r-cairo, different versions of CRAN Cairo packages by install.packages('Cairo') and also different versions of R, none worked. Texts always get distorted as in above example.

As suggested by Simon Urbanek, this problem may be solved by changing the default font:
CairoFonts(regular="sans:style=Regular")

https://github.com/s-u/Cairo/issues/49
